# How to show a message on screen for a few seconds?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a message on screen after the user presses a button. I then want the message to disappear after about a second. Preferably it would fade away instead of a hard disappear.

I would rather not lock up the UI during the display of the message. In fact, I would like the timer to restart for the message if the button is pressed again. I'm unsure of whether to use NSTimer, dispatch_after, or if there are other options.

I currently plan to use an NSTimer and a UI label to achieve this, and I will just live with a hard disappear. Is that the best way to do it?

EDIT: To clarify, the message will not necessarily be the same every single time that the button is pushed. I'm not entirely sure if this is relevant though.

Comment: You can do this with an animationWithDuration and a completion handler to reset values of animation.

Comment: You want something like those white text on semitransparent black, round rect prompts that used to appear and fade away when e.g. Xcode succeeded in building a project a couple of years ago. Or what the iOS Stack Exchange app does when you up-vote a comment, etc.?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I would like it to be much like some text on a powerpoint slide that shows up on the existing slide and then fades away after a second while the slide remains the same. The only difference being that my "slide" contains a button that causes the appearance of the text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted after researching what was suggested in the comment by @mn1. I used animateWithDuration to fade the label away. Here is some example code:

```
myLabel.hidden = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.myLabel.alpha = 0
})
```

Answer (score 11):

This code became shorter with iOS 10. Thanks to @fatihyildizhan

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Wait Please!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false, block: { _ in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)} )
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3 Solution:**

```
  // Define a view
  var popup:UIView!
  func showAlert() {
    // customise your view
    popup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
    popup.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor

    // show on screen
    self.view.addSubview(popup)

    // set the timer
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.dismissAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

  func dismissAlert(){
    if popup != nil { // Dismiss the view from here
      popup.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```

**Swift 2 Solution:**

```
  // Define a view
  var popup:UIView!
  func showAlert() {
    // customise your view
    popup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
    popup.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // show on screen
    self.view.addSubview(popup)

    // set the timer
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("dismissAlert"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

  func dismissAlert(){
    // Dismiss the view from here
    popup.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  // Don't forget to call showAlert() function in somewhere
```

Comment: Hi, I made a extension for UIView and want to put this code in an extension, how can I access the view (self.view.addSubView) from the extension? I thought of passing it as a parameter to the function but I feel like this is not a nice code to send the whole view as param.

Answer (score 5):

This shows an Alert View on screen and auto closes after 1 second. You can set the time.

```
 var alert:UIAlertController!
    func showAlert() {
        self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Wait Please!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        self.presentViewController(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("dismissAlert"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func dismissAlert(){
        // Dismiss the alert from here
        self.alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: An alert would actually cover the button and prevent interaction with the entire app. I am looking for a way to just display some text to the user rather than an obtrusive alert.

Answer (score 1):

the following solution

```
myLabel.hidden = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.myLabel.alpha = 0
})
```

got renamed to

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.myLabel.alpha = 0
    })
```

and don't forget to set your table in viewDidLoad to

```
mylabel.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 5, taking from the excellent ideas above, the following creates a fading message using a simple function.

First create variable to call later.

```
    var fadingLabel: UILabel!
```

Create an initially hidden label in viewDidLoad() as follows (adjust the constraints as needed)

```
    // Fading Label
    fadingLabel = UILabel()
    fadingLabel.text = "Text"
    view.addSubview(fadingLabel)
    fadingLabel.isHidden = true

    fadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fadingLabel.topAnchor.constraint    (equalTo: mapView.topAnchor,   constant:     60).isActive = true
    fadingLabel.leftAnchor.constraint   (equalTo: mapView.leftAnchor,  constant:     20).isActive = true
    fadingLabel.widthAnchor.constraint  (equalTo: mapView.widthAnchor, multiplier:  0.2).isActive = true
    fadingLabel.heightAnchor.constraint (equalToConstant: 20                           ).isActive = true
```

The following function will show a label and then fade it slowly away over three seconds.

```
func fadeMessage(message: String, color: UIColor, finalAlpha: CGFloat) {
    fadingLabel.text          = message
    fadingLabel.alpha         = 1.0
    fadingLabel.isHidden      = false
    fadingLabel.textAlignment = .center
    fadingLabel.backgroundColor     = color
    fadingLabel.layer.cornerRadius  = 5
    fadingLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    fadingLabel.font = appBoldFont(size: 14.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.fadingLabel.alpha = finalAlpha
    })
}
```

As an example, call the function using,

```
fadeMessage(message: "Saved", color: .blue, finalAlpha: 0.0)
```

Set the final alpha to about 0.4 if you want the message to remain discreetly, or to zero if you want it to disappear.